# SelectedIndex goes to -1 even if i set it to 1

Tags: c#, wpf

i'm working on a project and i'm stuck, hope you all can help me :)

I have a DropDownButton, the problem is that the ObservableCollection it is binded to changes when you click on it. I know that when you add/remove an ObservableCollection, the SelectedIndex is set to -1 and the SelectedItem is set to null. Knowing that my solution was to set the SelectedIndex to 1 immediatly after removing the last (index 1) item on my ObservableCollection and adding one new item at that index.

But when i click on the button, the ObservableCollection is modified like i said, the SelectedIndex is set to 1, but in the program the DropDownButton shows nothing (it shows index -1).

**The code for my MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Controls:SplitButton x:Name="clipboard" 
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
    Width="168"
    SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding CopyType}"
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="302,248,0,0" Height="36" Click="clipboard_Click"
    Visibility="Hidden">
    <Controls:SplitButton.IconTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Width="15"
           Height="20"
           Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}, Path=Foreground}">
                <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                    <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_clipboard_variant}" />
                </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
            </Rectangle>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Controls:SplitButton.IconTemplate>
</Controls:SplitButton>
```

**The code for my ClipboardAction class** (where the SelectedIndex and the Observable collection are binded)

```
public class ClipboardAction
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> copyType = new ObservableCollection<string> { "copy to clipboard", "copy password #1" };

    private int copyNumber = 0;

    public List<string> GeneratedPasswords { get; set; }

    public int SelectedIndex { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> CopyType { get => copyType; set => copyType = value; }
    public int CopyNumber { get => copyNumber; set => copyNumber = value; }

    public ClipboardAction(List<string> generatedPasswords)
    {
        this.GeneratedPasswords = generatedPasswords;
    }

    public string Copy()
    {
        switch (SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                Clipboard.SetText(string.Join("\r\n ", GeneratedPasswords));
                return "Copied to clipboard! :)";
            case 1:
                Clipboard.SetText(GeneratedPasswords[CopyNumber]);
                if (CopyNumber + 1 == GeneratedPasswords.Count)
                {
                    CopyNumber = 0;
                    CopyType.RemoveAt(1);
                    CopyType.Add($"copy password #{CopyNumber + 1}");
                    return "All passwords copied! :D";
                }
                else
                {
                    CopyType.RemoveAt(1);
                    CopyType.Add($"copy password #{CopyNumber + 1}");
                    SelectedIndex = 1;
                    CopyNumber++;
                    return $"Password #{CopyNumber}";
                }

            default:
                break;
        }

        return "error";
    }
}
```

Code of clipboard_Click:

```
private void clipboard_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    clip_text.Content = clipboardAction.Copy();
}
```

Comment: Done, i left all the code in the ClipboardAction so you can see if i have anything wrong related to fields and properties. @CamiloTerevinto

Comment: You can try setting the binding mode and update trigger manually for your selected index binding. Also, I don't see where `clipboard_Click` is defined.

Comment: @S.C. I tried changing the mode to TwoWays but it didn't work. clipboard_Click is defined in MainWindow.xaml.cs.
I added the code of clipboard_Click in the main post.